# Penscratch 2 - changing color of the main block

Tags: css

I am using "Penscratch 2" theme. I would like to change the color of the main block with text (not sure what's the proper term for this) from the default white to something else (e.g., let's say, pink). Is it possible to do so using the function marked on the picture provided below? If so, what should I add in that field? If not, how else can I do it without purchasing the premium plan (which I cannot afford)?

I know nothing about CSS. :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMEtp.png

Answer (score 0):

You can put `pinkBackground` in additional CSS Class, then you will have to add the following code into your Additional CSS, **Dashboard > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS**.

```
.pinkBackground {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Keep in mind you should use the [hex code](https://www.color-hex.com/) in order to be able to set a specific color, so in this case, you can use the hex pink which would be `background-color: #ffc0cb;`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would need to purchase a Premium Plan to activate CSS customization via the Dashboard option you mentioned. I was hoping such basic customization could be done via the tiny extra panel from the link I provided.

Comment: You can use this plugin to add extra CSS, https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/